# ¿Actualizar en tiempo real o actualizar cada segundo el resultado de una consulta en php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo una practica a realizar. ya tengo un proyecto que gráfica resultados, pero ahora tiene que ser en tiempo real la actualización o al menos cada ciertos segundos.
en el index.php donde esta el foreach es donde muestro el resultado de la consulta. para mi ejemplo tengo esto
vista index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ventas realizadas</th>
      <th>usuario</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($consulta as $consultas): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?=$consultas['ventas_realizadas']  ?></td>
          <td><?=$consultas['usuario']  ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

en el controlador index.php tengo lo siguiente

```
<?php
require 'funciones.php';
require 'config.php';
$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
if (!$conexion) {
    echo "error";
}
$consulta = obtenerdatos($conexion);
require 'vista/index.php';
?>
```

En el archivo de funciones.php tengo

```
<?php

function conexion($bd_config){
  try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['pass']);
    return $conexion;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function obtenerdatos($conexion){
  $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT SUM(ventas.id_usuario) ventas_realizadas, uusario.usuario FROM ventas JOIN uusario on ventas.id_usuario = uusario.id GROUP BY uusario.id");
  $resultado = $resultado->fetchAll();
  return($resultado);
}
?>
```

ahora, la cuestion es que no puedo hacer que se actualice la tabla sin la necesidad de presionar f5. he visto ejemplos con ajax, pero solo actualiza un echo y no un vector para recorrerlo con los resultados como por ejemplo este codigo

```
//php.add
<?php
echo rand(0,100);
?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeNumber() {
        value = $('#value').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#value').text(data);
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(changeNumber, 3000);
});
```

Les agradezco su ayuda u orientación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo más fácil que puedes hacer es crear un index.html, agregarle un iframe que contenga tu index.php y hagas que se actualice cada segundo

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Reload iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="index.php" id="reloadIframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
  <script>
    const iframe = document.getElementById("reloadIframe")
    setInterval(() => {
      iframe.src = "index.php";
    }, 1000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

hay otras mejores maneras de hacerlo, el ejemplo que pusiste con ajax por ejemplo es uno de esos, si lo quieres hacer con ajax, crea otro controlador que llame a una vista donde contengas la tabla, luego llames a esa vista desde el ajax y lo renderices en un elemento html mediante un id

espero haberte ayudado un poquito :)